Convert a Dataset into a list of lists and back to a Dataset
I'm looking for elegant, minimal, robust, idiomatic ways to turn a simple tabular Dataset into a list of lists and then back into a Dataset again.
Here is a simple tabular Dataset:
ds = Dataset[
 {
  <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 8|>,
  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> 8, "c" -> 11|>,
  <|"a" -> 9, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 14|>
  }
 ]

desired output:
listOfLists = {
{"a", "b", "c"}, 
{3, 5, 8}, 
{6, 8, 11}, 
{9, 11, 14}
}

Here is my own attempt at writing these functions, which is rather verbose and not very elegant:
datasetToLists[ds_] := {Normal@Keys[ds][[1]]}~Join~Normal@Values[ds];
listsToDataset[lists_] := Dataset[
   AssociationThread[lists[[1]] -> #] & /@ lists[[2 ;; -1]]
   ];



Why do you want to do this when you can simply do Export["file.csv", ds]? Also, what about ImportString[ExportString[ds, "CSV"]]?

@Domen, thanks, I never thought of using ExportString

If the overall purpose is to export Dataset to a CSV file, then you can simply use Export directly:
Export["file.csv", ds]

If you really want to produce a list of lists, you can use ExportString to a CSV, followed by ImportString:
ImportString[ExportString[ds, "CSV"]]
(* {{"a", "b", "c"}, {3, 5, 8}, {6, 8, 11}, {9, 11, 14}} *)


My main focus is to produce a list of lists, actually, as some computations are clunky to do on Datasets. Thanks for your solution.
